# Matrix Day Calendar

Tags: matrix, pixelandtonic, calendar

We are using Matrix to make a company calendar. We would like to enter the events into a matrix table one month at a time but display only the current day's events. We are trying to search a matrix date field and check if it matches the current day.

```
{schedule search:date="={current_time}" sort="asc"}
```

Has anyone done this before? Suggestions/help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The search condition would never match as {date} and {current_time} both output the UNIX Time (number of seconds since 1 January 1970). You would need to have IF condition with MATRIX variable tag like:

```
{schedule orderby="date" sort="asc"}

{if "{date format='%Y%m%d'}" == "{current_time format='%Y%m%d'}"}

{!-- Put other tags here --}

{/if}

{/schedule}
```

Comment: If you have any conditionals within the display of your events from the matrix field, you may want to wrap the outer conditional with an early parsing conditional add-on, such as croxton's ifelse or switchee.  But you can certainly still use the conditional without using such an add-on.

Comment: Thank you this worked perfect for us. Now another question: Is there a way to display the events by week using a similar concept? And could we display tomorrow using the same concept?